# ajax post selector as data in opencart "add to cart" button

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, opencart

Recently I was learning opencart develop,I found a weird thing.
We know the "add to cart" in product info page is using Ajax,and below the js code:

```
$('#button-cart').bind('click', function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'index.php?route=checkout/cart/add',
        type: 'post',
        data: $('.product-info input[type=\'text\'], .product-info input[type=\'hidden\'], .product-info input[type=\'radio\']:checked, .product-info input[type=\'checkbox\']:checked, .product-info select, .product-info textarea'),
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (json) {
            /** code  **/
        });
    });
```

the post data is like a jQuery selector.why the post data isn't value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This behaviour is implemented in [`jQuery.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/). You can set an Object, String or Array as a `data` value. If You provide an array of DOM objects jQuery will try to transform them to *key => value* pairs where the key is the form element's name and the value is the form element's value.

This is really handy especially in situations like this for products in OpenCart when we do not know how many options and of which type may the product have so we will select all possibilities (even they may not be present - then they are not posted) and hand them over to the AJAX request.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
if (isset($this->request->post['quantity'])) {
                $quantity = $this->request->post['quantity'];
            } else {
                $quantity = 1;
            }
```

Comment: $quantity = $this->request->post['quantity'];    this code can get post value of quantity,but I just wonder why post data is jquery selector not certain value.

Answer (score 0):

Well mainly opencart in cart addition has also options available as such, also multiple products and etc, since cart allows you to edit till one point products you have in your cart its only natural that you would use a selector and not a certain value.